# Find all orders associated with a specific coupon

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

I'm using the following SQL query to get all orders associated with coupons from Woocommerce.

Is it possible to do the same but find the orders for a specific coupon code? My coupon is called "FIRST30".

```
SELECT pc.post_title AS coupon_name,
       pc.post_excerpt AS coupon_description,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'discount_type'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_ids'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_categories' AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_categories,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'customer_email'     AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS customer_email,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_limit'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_count'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS total_usaged,
       po.ID AS order_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_email'      AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'  AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_order_total'        AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS order_total
FROM `wp_posts` AS pc
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmc ON  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_items` AS woi ON pc.post_title = woi.order_item_name
    AND woi.order_item_type = 'coupon'
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS po ON woi.order_id = po.ID
    AND po.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND po.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-refunded') -- Added needed order status over here.
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmo ON po.ID = pmo.post_id
WHERE pc.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
GROUP BY pc.post_title,
         pc.post_excerpt,
         po.ID
ORDER BY po.ID DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the follows to get all order related to your coupon -

```
global $wpdb;
$coupon = 'FIRST30';
$query = "SELECT
        p.ID AS order_id
        FROM
        {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON p.ID = oi.order_id
        WHERE
        p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND
        p.post_status IN ('" . implode("','", array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses())) . "') AND
        oi.order_item_type = 'coupon' AND
        oi.order_item_name = '" . $coupon . "';";

$orders = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```